# MFP8 - WASND installation Issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to install MFP Product version: 8.0.0.00-20170125-0919 in my QA environment on WASND 8.5.5. Server topology is, DMGR, DB, WAS are in a Private VLAN and  WEB(IHS) server in public VLAN. Seems like I missed some JNDI property.

In MFP Console, I am getting the below error:

```
FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found.
FWLSE3030E: The runtime "mfp" does not exist in the MobileFirst administration database. The database may be corrupted.
```

In MFP Console - Administration DB, Live Update, and Push Service are showing inactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the JNDI properties such as mfp.admin.proxy*. under "Table 4. JNDI properties for administration service: proxies" in this link : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/r_wladmin_jndi_property_list.html#r_wladmin_jndi_property_list

Also verify that jmx JNDI properties are correctly set. You can find the JXM properties that needs to be set from the link : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/c_wasnd_topol.html